# Webpack bundle files placed outside Project folder

Tags: webpack

Is it possible to create/add to the bundle components that are outside the project folder

Folders Structure

```
Project1
--src
----components

Project2
--src
----components
```

What should be done in webpack.config.js in order to add components from one project to the other (assuming that node_modules are the same).
Using Webpack3.

Comment: did you solve the problem..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you specify your output information, you can use `path.resolve` with `..` to access higher level directories.

So you would add path to your webpack.config:

```
const path = require("path");
```

And then within your build configuration that you are exporting, you can modify your path like such, which would go to a `dist` folder three folders up from your config file's location:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./../../../dist"),
    filename: "app.bundle.js"
}
```

`__dirname` is a global read-only variable that should automatically be set to the path of your `webpack.config.js`.

If you mean to source the build from the external source, you should be able to set your entry point to the other project in a similar manner.  In this example, the path would resolve two levels higher from the path of your webconfig and then locate `app.tsx` under `Project2`, `src`, `components`.

```
entry: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "./../../Project2/src/components") + "/app.tsx" ]
```

Comment: I did try this yesterday 
const financialDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './../../Microservices/Financial//skeleton-esnext-webpack/src/');

entry: { financial: [financialDir + 'index.js']

and there is always the same error 

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\MyProject\src\Microservices\Financial\src\index.js' in 'C:\MyProject\src\Presentation\WebPresentation'

Comment: facing same issue! @АндрейСафонов I was wondering if you could resolve this error

Comment: He, @doobean.  Did you already find the issue?  You could try adding some debug output to make sense of what path.resolve is parsing in your case.  For example, you could try adding console.log(financialDir + 'index.js'); in your script file and see if that is a valid path to your entry index.js.

Comment: @doobean - Nah, I ended up exporting the project2 as a plugin and use it as an external library.